# Scrolling on a dropdown which is absolute and prevent the parent div from also scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to prevent the parent div from also scrolling when I'm scrolling inside a dropdown. Is there a way to do this on jquery or javascript? I did this:

```
$('#scrollableDropdown').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        var e0 = e.originalEvent,
            delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

        this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

but I think it only works on preventing a body scroll..

Comment: Could you create a **snippet** along your HTML/CSS and JQuery Code? Also helpful if you could create a **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Call function name cancelBubble as shown below, it will stop event bubbling.**

```
$('#scrollableDropdown').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
    var e0 = e.originalEvent,
        delta = e0.wheelDelta || -e0.detail;

    this.scrollTop += ( delta < 0 ? 1 : -1 ) * 30;
   cancelBubble(e)
});

function cancelBubble(e) {
    var evt = e ? e : window.event;
    if (evt.stopPropagation) evt.stopPropagation();
    if (evt.cancelBubble != null) evt.cancelBubble = true;
}
```